# Access HTTPS / :443 through VPN in this Python urllib.request library, when blocked

Tags: python, github, proxy, network-programming, vpn

I am using [gh-issues-import](https://github.com/IQAndreas/github-issues-import) to migrate issues between GitHub and a GitHub Enterprise server. The problem I have is, our GHE requires going through a VPN proxy, while GitHubs API requires HTTPS route to access. I can only get one or the other, but having a hell of a time finding a way to access both via the same Python project using urllib.requests. Here is a scaled down script I used to utilize the library that is failing in gh-issues-import...

```
import urllib.request

# works through VPN (notice able to use http), requires VPN
GitHubEnterpriseurl = "http://xxxxx/api/v3/"   
req = urllib.request.Request(GitHubEnterpriseurl)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
json_data = response.read()
print(json_data)

# does not work on VPN due to https path, but fine outside of VPN
req = urllib.request.Request("https://api.github.com")
response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
json_data = response.read()
print(json_data)
```

I have tried other HTTP libraries and comes down to the VPN blocking access to the `https://api.github.com`. What are some solutions for this? Can I create a script on another server, my VPN has access to, and simply clone the requests and route the data?

*** I am able to connect to https://api.github.com using VPN through the browser (Chrome / Firefox) but when running any command line tools or this script to access it fails.**

Comment: Put an entry in your machines localhost file to override DNS for the VPN gateway to make sure it routes to the correct ip address. ie: on linux /etc/hosts

Comment: @user590028 I tried a few option already on that and just not familiar enough with how that works. The github api redirects to various IP addresses. Are you suggestion I point `https://api.gitub.com` to `127.0.0.1` or to my IP?